# Store and stream video simultaneously with Android Media Recorder

Tags: android, video, stream, store, mediarecorder

I wish to stream video, whilst storing it on the devices SD card (the device streamed from, not the device receiving the stream).

Is this possible? I've looked around and have found many similar questions without definitive answers.

If not, any alternatives?